# Is it reliable to use Gits functionality from Netbeans?

Tags: git, version-control, netbeans, versioning

Is it reliable to use Gits functionality from Netbeans?

If you use Netbeans editor, what do you use for Gits?

Comment: @UsmanSaleem but how do you get habbit keep tying commit all the time? Sometime I might forget or come lazy to do this.

Comment: As with almost any other skill out there, you learn to commit regularly and with meaningful log messages through practice and repetition.  You'll learn more about git working with the command line tools, and you'll be able to interact with your repository even when you don't have your favorite editor available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git features are more and more complete on NetBeans (See [Git Plan](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_plan)).
This [blog post](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/netbeans_7_git_plugin_small) from last August reported:

> Now the NetBeans Git Plugin supports all the major operations, including:
>
> - Clone (with different protocols: git, ssh, rsync, http+s, ftp), Fetch, Checkout and Push
> - Branch management: create, checkout + merge
> - Hard, Soft resets
> - History browsing
> - Show changes
> - Capable repository browser
> - Show Annotations - NetBeans shows the hash (treeish) for each line of code in the editor
> - Automatic creation of patch files ("Export uncommitted changes")

The target for a complete Git integration with Netbeans remains 7.1 though.